# How can I open Google Chrome from the terminal with the URL "localhost:3000"?

Tags: bash, google-chrome, gnome-terminal

Whenever I try to open Google Chrome with the URL "localhost:3000" it messes up and simply opens a blank tab with no URL. After some testing I've figures out it is the ":" messing it up. This works:

```
$ google-chrome www.gmail.com
```

but this does not work

```
$ google-chrome localhost:3000
```

nor this

```
$ google-chrome "localhost:3000"
```

How can I open Google Chrome with this URL?
I am using Ubuntu, bash script, and the gnome-terminal.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Have you tried?

```
google-chrome http://localhost:3000
```

Answer (score 19):

Got the following message:

```
zsh(or bash): command not found: google-chrome (or chromium-browser)
```

Solved my problem:

```
open http://localhost:3000
```

{ I use Google Chrome as a default browser  }

Comment: I really like this answer, since it is browser-agnostic. It opens the URL in the default browser, whatever it is.

Comment: `chromium-browser`, `chrome`, `google-chrome`, `open`, and `chromium` are all `command not found` for me, using bash in linux

Comment: `open` links to `xdg-open` on my system, and that is a fantastically useful command to know.  Can open local files in various apps based on type, including those nasty PDFs.

Answer (score 5):

This is what worked for me:

```sh
open  -a "Google Chrome" http:localhost:3000
```

Comment: Excellent solution, especially for situations where Chrome is not the default browser.

Answer (score 2):

I don't seem to have this problem.

```
chromium "http://localhost:8889"
chromium "http://127.0.0.1:8889"
```

One quick suggestion would be to check to see if `127.0.0.1:3000` works (newer versions of ubuntu seem to have an issue resolving "localhost" instead of the numbered IP address.)

Answer (score 0):

As stated beautifully by @Bexultan Myrzatayev, if google chrome is your default browser, simply

```
open http://localhost:8000
```

Comment: What does this answer bring to the table? Honest question.